# How to insert infinity symbol to X axis of Matlab Bar graph?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

How can I add the infinity symbol to X axis of Matlab Bar graph?

Naturally it is possible to insert the infinity symbol i.e. `'\infty'` for xlabel, as seen in the last line of the inserted code.
But, I want to add the infinity sign in the x axis bar not in the x axis label.
How can I do that?
For the sake of detailed clarification, the following script is added bellow:

```
data=[1 2 3; 1 3 4; 3 1 2];
bar(data)
set(gca,'YLim',[0 3])
set(gca,'YTick',[0:0.5:3])
set(gca, 'YTickLabel',num2str(get(gca,'YTick')','%02.1f%%'))
set(gca,'Xtick',1:3,'XTickLabel',{'\infty' ; '20 dB'; '15 dB'})
xlabel('\infty dB') % x-axis label
```

[image: Image showing problem]

Comment: Have you seen this [related question](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/164483)? It might be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, That doesn't work for the case above. @Arpi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this solution, using [`format_tick`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23841-format-tick-labels--extended-) function from File Exchange?:

```
data=[1 2 3; 1 3 4; 3 1 2];
bar(data)
set(gca,'YLim',[0 3])
set(gca,'YTick',[0:0.5:3])
set(gca, 'YTickLabel',num2str(get(gca,'YTick')','%02.1f%%'))
set(gca,'Xtick',1:3)
format_ticks(gca, {'$\infty$' ; '20 dB'; '15 dB'})
```

[image]

I left out the `xlabel` because it interfers with the `Xtick`, but probably that can be easily moved to lower position.

**EDIT:**
To fix the overlap of `Xtick` and `xlabel` add this to the end of the code:

```
xlabh = get(gca,'XLabel');
set(xlabh,'Position',get(xlabh,'Position') - [0 .1 0])
```

[image]

Comment: @mohsen You're welcome. I extended the answer with the code which fixes the overlap problem.